# Symfony Url Generator producing different URLs from the same Route before and after login

Tags: php, symfony, url, routes

I currently using Symfony Kernel and Routing within a custom framework and I have run into a curious problem. Using the same Route:

```
$collection->add('article_edit', new Route('/articles/edit/{alias}', array(
    '_controller' => 'AppBundle:Article:edit'
)));
```

Using this Url Generator code

```
$url = $this->generateUrl('article_edit',array('alias' => 'test'));
```

Before login, the Url Generator produces

> /articles/edit/test

And after login, it produces

> http://localhost/testsite/articles/edit/test

Without anything being changed, what could be happening here since I want the same result consistently.

Thanks

Comment: The difference I see is url turning to `ABSOLUTE_URL` after login. However, the default is `ABSOLUTE_PATH`. Try `$url = $this->generateUrl('article_edit',array('alias' => 'test'), 0);` See what it returns it for you even after login.

Comment: @Jeet - Even when I change the url type to ABSOLUTE_PATH the url still generates different URLs. In fact it also changes when I submit a form i.e. use $_POST variables.

Comment: Please post the headers you send before and after login.

Comment: Right now have done this

`$routes = $this->get('router');`
`$collection = $routes->getRouteCollection();`
`$collection->add('stack_question', new \Symfony\Component\Routing\Route('/stack/{alias}', ['_controller' => 'AppBundle:Default:index']));`

`$url = $this->generateUrl('stack_question', ['alias' => 'test']);`

In both cases have the same result

"/app_dev.php/stack/test" , so, there is no problem with Symfony component, maybe some bug in certain version ?

Comment: Pay attantion on Router in Symfony, it uses Router from Framework Bundle, so maybe your problem about poor initialize your router component ?

Comment: Can you please add your routing and security configuration settings?

Comment: @KidBinary I use standart symfony application, with FosUserBundle as user managment, so my configuration from symfony book. Maybe is sence to use xdebug and look for config Router in symfony framework application.

Comment: How are you displaying/using the URL, so you know it's wrong? Maybe you are passing this URL somewhere and some listener rewrites it. Basically, please show some code using $url variable.

Comment: `/articles/edit/test` is somehow relative. It will use you current environment via proper `app*.php` file. After login you route is different - `http://localhost/testsite/articles/edit/test` - maybe you are using production environment with old/cached routes compiled? Try clearing your cache and make sure you don't switch environments.

Answer (score 2):

I can see that "/articles/edit/test" and "http://localhost/testsite/articles/edit/test" are same url just with difference of site url in it.

if you use your "generateUrl" method as following it will generate always same url. It should generate "http://localhost/testsite/articles/edit/test" always

```
$url = $this->generateUrl('article_edit',array('alias' => 'test', UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_URL));
```

Also dont forget to use following class in namespace section

```
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting your host in
`app/config/services.yml`

```
parameters:
    router.request_context.host: www.yourdomain.com
    router.request_context.scheme: http
    router.request_context.base_url: /your/path
```

More Info:
https://symfony.com/doc/3.3/console/request_context.html